# What is a reasonable terminal size across Linux distributions?

Tags: linux, text-based

I'm working on a Curses-based roguelike; it should (and does) work in both Linux and Windows (various flavours of each).

Currently, I'm enforcing a hard requirement of "your terminal size must be `80x25` to play. Please fix it and come back" to ensure I have a consistent UI.

This works on Windows. But not on Linux; it seems that Ubuntu, at least, uses a terminal size of `80x24` instead.

Since Google is not useful, what can I reasonably expect as far as terminal size support across various Linux distros?

(If it is `80x24` or even as low as `80x20`, I can probably work with that.)

Comment: This seems like something the users of Superuser may be better equipped to answer.

Comment: @JoshPetrie possibly, although I posted it here because it's more relevant to game development IMO.

Comment: @ashes999 I think you should add the text-based tag.

Comment: Go with the dwarf fortress method: opengl rendering quads, sampling a texture atlas of ascii characters.  It scales to any width of characters, allows coloring, and and can be replaced with actual graphics by eager modders.  (Please don't really do this.)

Comment: @SethBattin using a terminal emulator instead of relying on the terminal itself is out-of-scope. Nice try though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with classic VT100 dimensions.  It's the kind of terminal that such things would be run on when it was actually a game you played on a terminal.

From http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/vt100.html I see that the display is 80x24 or 132x14 character cells, optional 132x24.

I don't recall playing it at the 132 resolutions, but 80x24 is "classic"

Comment: Okay, thanks. Can you suggest why DOS/Windows defaults to 80x25, then?

Comment: @ashes999 - a hangover from the original IBM PC I would guess, it used a CGA adapter which offered 40x25 and 80x25 modes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_Graphics_Adapter#Standard_text_modes

Comment: VT100 and such terminals were before the PC and CGA.  VT100 came out in '78.  Think about the fact that you've got 200 pixels height on that CGA.  200 / 8 = 25, so you can't really get a nice "24" out of it.  Numerically and computationally, there was probably some nice reason for 320x200 as opposed to 320x198 (24*8).

Comment: Ah and the /8 is about an 8 pixel tall font character.  Its all about the pixels and font rez if you dig deep.